# GWT: Using External Jar

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I am trying to figure out how to use external jar in GWT project.
I referred http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWTModules/article.html and it worked perfectly.
But the example explained using another project being included in the GWT project's build path instead of including the jar of that project.

I know this should not make a difference but when I created the jar of the external project (including sources) and used it in the client GWT gave me following error:

```
The import com.person cannot be resolved
```

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using external gwt library jar file in your gwt eclipse project you have to add that jar file in library tab from java build path:

[image]

Comment: Yes. I did that and as I am using Eclipse, it is not giving me any compile error. But when I do "GWT Compile Project", it is giving me "cannot be resolved" error.

Comment: If you have gwt compile problem, you have to inherit require gwt module in your main gwt module.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use external jar and use that jar classes in your client side. you have to inherit module package entry in client gwt module.gwt.xml

Just example a. `com.test.Module2.xml` so you have do entry like

```
<inherits name='com.test.Module2'/>
```