# creating a GWT application with gflot

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications, flot

So im looking into creating a GWT project with gflot.  Can anyone provide a short tutorial on how to get started.  Im kind of a newbie when it comes to java projects in eclipse.  I understand how to create a GWT project in eclipse and I have the gflot jar files but I do not know how to connect the two.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The gflot project provides a sample project:  http://code.google.com/p/gflot/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgooglecode%2Fgflot%2Fexamples%2Fclient

Answer (score 2):

You have to download gflot jar file and use it as external jar library in your gwt project in eclipse.

You can see the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988653/gwt-using-external-jar/13988769#13988769) for more details.